# Word delimitors for python coding style?

Tags: python, vim

PEP8 use `_` as a word delimitor, for example, a method named `get_context_data`.

<kbd>caw</kbd> is so cool when you want change `get_context_data` to `set_context_data`.

I googled and added `set iskeyword-=_` to my vimrc.

But another problem comes with this change, I can autocomplete the method name when I type `get_`, menu shows me `context` not `context_data` I want,  is there a way to solve the problem?

Comment: does it only happen in py files?

Comment: @Kent not only for python, I use `set iskeyword-=_` globally and use supertab and autocomplpop for code complete.

Comment: oh, I just misunderstood your question.. now I see why you removed `_` from iskeyword. you want to make it easy to modify the part between `_`s....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By changing the `'iskeyword'` setting, you influence (and potentially break) a lot of things; among them *word* motions (`w`, `e`, etc.), completions (your problem here), and syntax highlighting.

I recommend keeping the original setting (after all, `get_context_data` as a single variable should probably also be represented by a single *word*). You can use my [camelcasemotion plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905) to work on the underscore-separated fragments. With the plugin, you can either override the original motions and text objects, or use `ca,w` instead of `caw`.

Answer (score 1):

Better don't change the iskeyword option. There are alot of commands need it. If you just want to make editing  underscore connected string (`a_b_c_d`) easier, you could try this mapping:

```
onoremap iu :<c-u>normal! T_vt_<cr>
onoremap au :<c-u>normal! F_vf_<cr>
```

with this mapping, (iu means In Underscore, you can change it). you could for example

```
get_cont[I]ext_data ( [I]:cursor)
```

you type `ciu` you got `get_[I]_data` ,  `diu` will do delete, `au` will do operation also on wrapped underscores.

But, for these cases, the above mapping does **not** work (or work **unexpectedly ^_***)

```
g[I]et_context_data -> [I]_context_data  (you could do bct_ instead)
get_context_dat[I]a -> get_context_[I]   (you could do ecT_ or T_cw instead)
```

Because the mapping doesn't work wordwise .you can make it suit your needs however.